# How can I have, in CSS, a double background color and the text centered in the second background color element?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, menuitem

I'd like to do something like this image:
[ul menu li tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV0Tx.png)

Should I use a double tag for every element?
For example:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <div class="outside"><li class="inside"><a href="#">Firefox</a></li></div>
    <div class="outside"><li class="inside"><a href="#">Chrome</a></li></div>
    <div class="outside"><li class="inside"><a href="#">Opera</a></li></div>
</ul>
```

Or maybe a double li tag?
I have tried in CSS the linear-gradient property, but with just one tag, and as I want to get the same result like in the image, it seems to me that there has to be two different tags with different background colors and the one with the black color just has to have a higher z-index property.

I'm quite new and a bit bad at design and styling, so I just can thank you so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pseudo element `::before` to create the left colored side

*Note, the `div`'s you used is invalid as a direct child of an `ul`, so I removed them*

```css
ul.menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.menu li {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
ul.menu a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 0 4px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.menu a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;
  background: gray;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Firefox</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Chrome</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Opera</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

Or a left `border`

```css
ul.menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.menu li {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
ul.menu a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 10px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Firefox</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Chrome</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Opera</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You **can** use linear-gradient, just place both values of the gradient to be at the same point
 **(ex: `gray 10%, black 10%`)** so they split the background at that point.

**Side Note:** You should also remove the outter `div`s around your `li` tags, because they are not valid inside `ul` element.

```css
ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

ul.menu li.inside {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, gray 10%, black 10%);
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px;
  width: 120px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="inside"><a href="#">Firefox</a></li>
  <li class="inside"><a href="#">Chrome</a></li>
  <li class="inside"><a href="#">Opera</a></li>
</ul>
```